# Missing "Recent HTTP Errors" in Traefik UI on Kubernetes

Tags: traefik

I've followed the standard install guide for Traefik on Kubernetes and am on the most recent version (v1.7.6). The screenshots on the website show a section under Health called "Recent HTTP Errors", but that part is missing on my Web UI dashboard.

I can't find any settings to enable/disable this feature. Is there any way to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

look at this

https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/api/#metrics

```
[api]
  [api.statistics]
    recentErrors = 10
```

Note that the dashboard GUI depends on the API to control how many recent errors to show. The default seems to be set to 0 so no errors are shown.

Comment: Thanks, @StarsL. This is for the API endpoint, not the dashboard though. I'll give you an upvote for the help, but this doesn't address the specific question I'm asking. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: According to the configuration of this API, the "Recent HTTP Errors" of the dashboard can be implemented. I have tested it. @Dan Bowling